# Comparing all properties of PSCustomObjects (Excel sheet data)

Tags: excel, powershell

I am working on a script for PowerShell to import data from 2 separate Excel sheets, compare all properties of these sheets and export a new Excel worksheet with this output.
The purpose of this script is to compare an updated excel sheet with a previous version and spot what has changed, what has been added and possibly even what has been removed.

I have been using the Import-Excel module to handle the first part, and `Compare-Object` for the data comparison. 
As far as I can tell `Import-Excel` imports the Excel data into a `System.Object` which is a hashtable of PSCustomObjects. Each PSCustomObject corresponds to a row in the Excel sheet.

I am running the following code:

```
$global:InputdataA = Import-Excel -Path $InputA -WorkSheetname $InputSheetA
$global:InputdataB = Import-Excel -Path $InputB -WorkSheetname $InputSheetB
$global:ReferenceObject = $InputdataA
$global:DifferenceObject = $InputdataB

$global:InputdataHeadersA = $InputdataA[0].psobject.properties.name
$global:InputdataHeadersB = $InputdataB[0].psobject.properties.name

$props = $InputdataHeadersA
$props += $InputdataHeadersB
$props = $props | Select -Unique

$compareResult = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ReferenceObject -DifferenceObject $DifferenceObject -Property $props -PassThru -CaseSensitive
```

---

I am using 2 excel files for testing:

Personnel_16_12_2018 - small2.xlsx (previous version)
Personnel_28_11_2018 - small2.xlsx (new version with changes and additions)

The files can be downloaded here:

https://ufile.io/bmstu
https://ufile.io/3z62x

---

The output I would like to see would be only the 7 entries that have been changed/added, with data from difference object (the new version of the excel sheet) This would represent the latest and "correct" data.

Currently I get an output from the compare-object, containing the 7 entries AND the 6 entries that have been changed from the reference object including side-indicator.

Is it possible to make the compare-object return only the changes or do I have to process the output afterwards?

Comment: Could you give some sample data that indicates the structure of your XLSX-files? If I compare 2 spreadsheets via `Compare-Object` and name each Headline in the `-Property` Argument, it works as expected

Comment: Hi Razorfen, I changed the code to include all headers in properties like this:

        $props = $InputdataHeadersA
        $props += $InputdataHeadersB
        $props = $props | Select -Unique
        $compareResult = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ReferenceObject -DifferenceObject $DifferenceObject -Property $props -PassThru -CaseSensitive #added array as properties

Now it returns all changes, but it returns the changed rows twice: once for the new and changed data and once for the old data including side indicator. How do I change this to get only the new and changed items?

Comment: Could you edit your above question and insert some sample data (two sample spreadsheets) and your desired output?

Comment: Post has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional information and the sample files, you could try something like this:

```
$oldFile = Import-Excel ".\personnel_28_11_2018---small2.xlsx"
$newFile = Import-Excel ".\personnel_16_12_2018---small2.xlsx"

$properties = "TRIAL_PK", "TRIALCOUNTRY_PK", "TRIALSSITE_PK", "ASSIGNMENT_LVL", "ROLE", "INT_EXT", "START_DATA", "END_DATE", "PERSONNELL_PK", "TITLE", "LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "ORGANIZATION_NAME"

$result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $oldFile -DifferenceObject $newFile -Property $properties -PassThru -CaseSensitive | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"}

$result | Select-Object $properties | Export-Excel ".\changed.xlsx"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job.

I am trying to find a way to identify and separate the changed data, because I am exporting it into excel and I would like to mark the changed data with a different formatting.

I need to find a solution for 1 or 2 of the problems below:
1: I would like to produce a filtered version of the compare-object result, containing only the changed data, other values should be null.
2: I would like a way to identify only the changed properties of the compare-object result  and in such a way that it can be used to navigate rows and columns in the excel sheet.